# What are the advantages of Kotlin programming language?

Tags: android, mobile, kotlin, android-developer-api

I am quite eager to know the advantages of Kotlin programming language over Java for Android application development as I would love to explore new things. If any one have any knowledge about it please do needful.

Thank you.

Comment: I want to compare kotlin with java for android application development.

Comment: yea, thank you for the comment, now it's more clear.

Answer (score 17):

I assume you asked about Kotlin versus Java for Android development.

Basically there are reasons to switch from Java to Kotlin for Android development:

1. Readable and concise code
2. Small runtime
3. Performance
4. Kotlin libraries

All this points described here:

1. [Develop Android apps with Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/)
2. [Using Project Kotlin for Android](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ReS3ep-hjxWA8kZi0YqDbEhCqTt29hG8P44aA9W0DM8/edit?hl=pl&forcehl=1#heading=h.v6i4iyf7kkxh)
3. [Checkout Awesome Kotlin for Android](https://github.com/JavaBy/awesome-kotlin#android)

Comment: Performance? Isn't it generating bytecode so it should be exactly the same performance as Java, or slower? It can't be faster at least, can it be?

Comment: Yep, Kotlin for JVM generates bytecode just like Java, but not in the same way as Java. For example you can inline one lambda in another, kotlin in this case will be faster.

Comment: awesome libraries

Comment: "Nice code" ? what type of reason is this?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub fixed

Comment: @SList thanks, I replaced link with link to android documentation about kotlin

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to see it here：http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/02/kotlin-1-0-released-pragmatic-language-for-jvm-and-android/